# problem with running OpenAI Cookbook's chatbot

Tags: python, streamlit, openai-api, gpt-3, chatgpt-api

I'm having trouble running the chatbot app in the OpenAI Cookbook repository.

## What I tried

I installed the necessary packages with 'pip install -r requirements.txt'. I made .env file with my OpenAI API Key, and inserted the code below in chatbot.py line 9.

```
import os
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
```

The setup above is by my guess, because the doc is totally unclear about how to set up.

I run the app in local by the command "streamlit run apps/chatbot-kickstarter/chat.py." It didn't work properly. The app run but when I entered text and pressed 'submit' button in the app, I got an error:

```
Uncaught app exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "F:\PythonProjects\openai-cookbook\apps\chatbot-kickstarter\chat.py", line 71, in <module>
response = query(messages)
  File "F:\PythonProjects\openai-cookbook\apps\chatbot-kickstarter\chat.py", line 51, in query
response = st.session_state['chat'].ask_assistant(question)
  File "F:\PythonProjects\openai-cookbook\apps/chatbot-kickstarter\chatbot.py", line 61, in ask_assistant
if 'searching for answers' in assistant_response['content'].lower():
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I use Python 3.10.6.

I would appreciate any help or guidance to resolve these issues.

Comment: Yes I did put the actual key string instead of "OPENAI_API_KEY"

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?

Comment: https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/issues/307

Comment: In the link, it is said that putting api key in chatbot.py fixes the problem but it doesn' work for me. The same result.

Comment: @Robert I just made .env file with my key (MY_ACTUAL_KEY=sk-XXXX) and inserted the code "import os
openai.api_key = os.getenv("MY_ACTUAL_KEY")" in line 9 in chatbot.py, and run the command "streamlit run apps/chatbot-kickstarter/chat.py" in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the key directly in chatbot.py just worked. It shouldn't be taken from environment variables.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this, if work accept the answer, otherwise i delete it

Try remove ['content'] from assistant_response

The error says "string indices must be integers"

This mean that you are trying to do something like this:

```
out = "a string object"["content"]
```

And it obviously wont work

Probably assistant_response is already a string or is the wrong object for what you're doing

PS:
A correct use of string indices is something like this:

```
out = "a string object"[0]
print(out)
>>> "a"
```

[Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3)